# Issue when toggling modal on Ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have an `Ajax` call and after success, it is calling another Ajax. During the success, it is actually toggling a `modal` and showing another `modal`. My code as below

```js
$("#passMloTag").click(function() {
  var passOrFailOrHandover = "pass";
  var srNumber = $("#srNumber").val();
  var currentStage = $("#currentStage").val();
  var remarksInmloProductionModal = $("#remarksInmloProductionModal").val();
  var assignedOa = $("#assignedOa").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "commonFiles/passFailHandover.php",
    data: {
      passOrFailOrHandover: passOrFailOrHandover,
      srNumber: srNumber,
      currentStage: currentStage,
      remarksInmloProductionModal: remarksInmloProductionModal,
      assignedOa: assignedOa
    },
    success: function(result) {
      callAjax("mloSupervisor.php", "mloProduction");
      var section = "mloProduction"; //This is setting a variable mloSupervisor. This variable will be used to differentiate user clicked which department
      $("#mloSupervisorProductionModal").modal('toggle');
      $("#success").modal('show');
    }
  });
});
```

**My Issue**

My issue is that after modal toggled, it goes into a black non responsive screen. I need to manually refresh the whole page in order to retrieve back the page. Does anyone know why this happening?

I tried to re-order the `modal` before `Ajax` call and also removed `#success` modal. But still the same issue persist.

**Edit 1**

The following code is the `callAjax` function

```js
function callAjax(pageName, departmentName) {
  var department = departmentName;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: pageName,
    data: {
      department: department
    },
    success: function(result) {
      $("#pages").html(result);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Not sure where problem might be .It would be good if you can create demo to reflect that behaviour .

Comment: What is modal plugin? Where it came from? and what is callAjax, can you show the definition of that function? Note that your comment after `var section ` make no sense because no other code will be able to use that variable because it's local in that function and nothing is using it.

Comment: @Swati: I tried to do the replication. But seems quite hard since many functions and php codes involved. However I can assure that `callAjax` function is working properly as I can see the result through the transparent non responsive black screen after modal toggled.

Comment: @jcubic: I am using `bootstrap`. `callAjax` is a function that is directing to a php page. Please ignore the variable `var section`. I tried to extract the code to post in here and the variable came in together. I updated my question to include `callAjax` function

Comment: I have no idea why you have this issue, but I think that this is not related to the code you've posted. The issue may be somewhere else. Maybe there is other click event on the same item or maybe you're not preventing the form and it send but somehow break. Try to minimize the code on your real project and check if you still get the same issue, then try to add back one by one snippets of code to make your whole app and check each time if it's still broken. If the app would be online I may check if I can debug this. If the app need to be private then you will need to debug it yourself.